# Time series forecasting with decision making

Tags: regression, neural-networks, forecasting, python, scikit-learn

I want to do forecasting for wind power generation but the problem with it is that when the wind speed is below 4 m/s the power output is zero. RNN based models do best when these type of conditions are not there. But with these consitions the RNN is not able to forecast properly. Look at the forecasting results below:

[image: wind_forecast_RNN]

As one can see most of the time I got negative results which is not possible.

I tried to using Gradient boosting regression which gave the following results.

[image: wind_forecast_GBR]

Still I'm not able to get those peak values and zero values. I don't think a single model would be able to do prediction here. So, my question is which models should I combine to get those decision making ability and regression ability?

Comment: Could you transform the data into integers and do count time series?

Comment: There is huge difference between data when converted into integer that is why data is nornalized between 0 to 1.

Comment: OK, can you bin your data into k bins between 0 and 1 after normalization?

Comment: What is k bin ?

Comment: Any number, say 20 bins.

Comment: You mean https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer.html ?? Let me try.

Comment: `KBinsDiscretizer` is not able to meet my requirement or maybe I'm not able to use it properly.

Comment: I don't know Python so I can't help you there.